# How to start an Alarm at specific Date and Time?

Tags: android, service, datepicker, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

How to start an alarm at specific time and date, Where i got time and date using `TimePicker` and  `DatePicker` . Even i can start an alarm at user specified time,but i can't do it for at user specified date. How can  i reach my goal?
The code  which i have already done.

```
package com.example.modifiedalarm;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    Calendar c;
    String abcd;
    TextView ed, tv;
    int hr, min, year, month, date;
    int time = 0;
    int daa = 0;

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        ed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settime);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gettime);
        c = Calendar.getInstance();

        hr = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
            i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");
            i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hr);
            i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, min);
            startActivity(i);
}});                

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // showDialog(time);
                new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, timeval, hr, min, true)
                        .show();

            }

        });

        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, dateval, year, month,
                        date).show();
            }
        });
    }


    OnDateSetListener dateval = new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int Year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            year = Year;
            month = monthOfYear;
            date = dayOfMonth;
            updatedate();
        }
    };


    OnTimeSetListener timeval = new OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hr = hourOfDay;
            min = minute;
            updatetime();
        }
    };

    public void updatedate() {
        tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(date).append("/").append(month).append("/").append(year));
        String og=tv.getText().toString();
        //int ogx=Integer.parseInt(og);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "the date is "+og, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        datecompare();

}   private void datecompare() {

    }
private void updatetime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ed.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hr).append(":").append(min));
        String b=hr + ":" + min;
        }

}
```

For Example:
i would like to set an alarm on 05-04-2013 12:00 pm .. How can i achieve that ??

Comment: Use a `Calendar` instance with the `set()` method. Show us what you have so we can help

Comment: @codeMagic  if i get Calender instance it will get the device time right ? ? so with that device time i cant do anything other than displaying.

Comment: No, you can set a date from there using the `field` constants available in the `Calendar` API

Comment: @codeMagic ... i have posted the code .. could you help me now where to edit ???

Answer (score 2):

```
    AlarmManager:
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            long when =0; 
            intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("eventName", eventName);
            intent.putExtra("eventDescription",eventDescription);

            // Get the AlarmManager service
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Setting_rgRepeatMode);
            selectedRadio=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            long repeatTime=0;

                cal.set(mYear,mMonth,mDay,mHour,mMinute,0);
                intent.putExtra("Flag",true);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                when=cal.getTimeInMillis();
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when, pendingIntent);
                return;

    BroadCastReceiver:

        public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       try {
//Here you can write your logic
                    Toast.makeText(context,bundle.getString("eventName"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int icon = R.drawable.event;
            CharSequence notiText = "Event Notification";
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notiText,time);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Setting.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,intent.getStringExtra("eventName"),intent.getStringExtra("eventDescription"), contentIntent);
            int SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED =  1;
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            Toast.makeText(context,"aavechhe "+intent.getBooleanExtra("Flag",false),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(intent.getIntExtra("month",0)==cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"aavechhe "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);
            }
            if(intent.getBooleanExtra("Flag",false))
                notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: here i am showing notification at specific time. but you can write  alarm code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I set a logout alarm for 5 minutes from now

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
```

you can do more with the date using the methods and fields available in **[Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)**. For example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstanc();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, JANUARY);
```

to set the month. Check that link and you can see all the different ways that you can set it. Use `set()` to set the field (month, day, etc...) and use `add()` to add to the field. This should help you get started anyway

**Edit**

Wherever you set your pending intent just use these variables you have set as the values

```
    private void updatedate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    c.set(Calendar.Month, month);            // `c` is the `Calendar` instance you defined earlier. Now we are setting the month on that instance
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);
    }
```

then when you click your `Button`

```
  b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         long alarmTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); // convert your calendar instance with the dates set to millis
            Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");
        i.putExtra("alarmTime", alarmTime);     //"alarmTime" will be used to get the time to set the alarm in your AlarmClock class
        startActivity(i);
}});
```

And the rest you know how to do if you are already setting a time. Hope this helps you

Comment: No this is not am looking for

Comment: Then what are you looking for? This is how you would set a specific date. See my edit

Comment: Dear @CodeMagic .. I already did that have you saw my code .. ??

Comment: I see where you call `get()` on the `Calendar` instance but not where you `set()` the fields such as the month, day, etc... You `get` the values in `onCreate()` but I don't see you setting them anywhere for your alarm

Comment: Where do you actually set your alarms right now? You said that you can start an alarm at a user specified time...post how you do that. Are you using `AlarmManager`?

Comment: No Am using Implicit intent 
 Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
 i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");
 i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hr);
 i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, min);
 startActivity(i);

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, you should be able to put that edit of code I added in your `onClick()` then just use `i.putExtra("time", alarmTime);` `alarmTime` is a long variable which we put the `Calendar` instance into after setting the month, day, etc...

Comment: Give up if you like but not necessary. If you explain why it isn't working if you tried what I suggested then maybe we can fix it. Also, you may want to look into using an `AlarmManager` to set your alarms

Comment: I have changed my edit. See if that helps you. You are just setting the date on your calendar instance on `updatedate()` then converting it to `millis` when you click your button and sending it to your `AlarmClock` class. Hope this helps